# Best way to call a function on a parent page after .load?

Tags: jquery

what is the best way to access a function on a parent page after an ajax call?  I want to avoid loading the same function multiple times.

index.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#header").load('header.jsp');
        });
        function user() {
            alert('user function');
        }
    </script>
```

header.jsp

```
user();
```

Comment: `$("#header").load('header.jsp', user);`??? I'm not sure what is your question in fact...

Comment: You might like to reword your question to "How do I...".  Questions with "Best..." will get close-voted as opinion based.

Comment: A woff8, sorry for the confusion, regardless your answer was right, passing the function within the load.